# Sort by value in nested array before Map

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, rxjs6

Using NG6 Rxjs to return some data via http.  I then split the returned data into two Observables.  Works great but I need to sort the data first, by a value(s) in a nested array.  I am able to sort the array after an event fires in the view, but not working when the page loads.

This code sorts by a value in the outer array:

```
return this.http
  .get(this.apiUrl + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
  .pipe(
    map((data: Array<any>) => {
    return {
      ungrouped: data.filter(d => d.id < 0),
      grouped: data.filter(d => d.id > 0).sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1)
    };
    }),
   catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

Tried this to sort by the nested value but no good:

```
return this.http
  .get(this.apiUrl + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
  .pipe(
    map((data: Array<any>) => {
    return {
      ungrouped: data.sort((a, b) => a.server.name < b.server.name ? -1 : 1).filter(d => d.id < 0),
      grouped: data.filter(d => d.id > 0).sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1)
    };
    }),
   catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

It seems dirty to sort each Observable. Can't I sort the data before passing to each Observable?

From my component:

```
this.appsApiService.getPatchGroups(appReconId)
  .subscribe(pg => {
    this.ungrouped_patchGroups = pg.ungrouped;
    this.grouped_patchGroups = pg.grouped;
  }
);
```

Comment: You could try chaining two different map statements, the first to perform the sort and the second to perform the two filters.

Comment: can you put the part of the code where you subscribe to the observable?

Comment: @Ricardo added it to the original post.

Comment: Since the Observable you are talking about is the http request, there is no other way of doing the sorting unless you have direct access to the back-end of the api. The phase you are doing the sorting now is the first phase possible on the client side, so I think that's all good.

Comment: Sorting by the name works, sorting by the server.name does not.